# "Undo" ComboBox DropButtonClick

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of `ComboBoxes` that are populated based on the previous `ComboBox` selection. So for example, `ComboBox3` is populated based on the value selected in `ComboBox2`. The "trigger" for populating `ComboBox3` is the `DropButtonClick` action. I have a message box pop up when there is no value in ComboBox2. This is working successfully - code below.

```
If Me.ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Please select all preceding comboboxes"
    ComboBox3.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
Else
    sh.Range("B2") = Me.ComboBox2.Value
End If
```

My issues is once the `Message Box` appears (as a result of there being no value in `ComboBox2`) `ComboBox3` still displays drops down values. Is there a way to undo the `ComboBox3 DropButtonClick Event` when there is no value in `ComboBox2`, so that `ComboBox3` never drops down?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly. I would have included the actual `Private Sub` declaration in the post, for more context; can you [edit] to clarify what you mean to "escape"?

Comment: Edited question for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: You could simply disable ComboBox3 and then enable it with the ComboBox2 event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can immediately close the drop-down window of the combo-box by simulating the "ESC" key:

```
  MsgBox "Please select all preceding comboboxes"
  ComboBox3.Value = ""

  ' close immediately the combo's dropdown window
  SendKeys "{ESC}{ESC}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something for you?

```
If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "" Then
    ComboBox2.SetFocus
Else
    sh.Range("B2") = Me.ComboBox2.Value
End If
```

When you want to click on the dropbutton of combobox3 it automaticly goes back to combobox2.